# How to Quickly Direct a Dragon’s Fire while Piloting her in Battle?

Tags: warfare, weapons, dragons, control

In this world, some dragons are bred by humans, some are feral. Some are domesticated and trained for work or war, while others are free, and can make lifelong friends with humans and their families. They are intelligent, and some of the older ones (too old for battle) can understand human speech.
It is clear that the army whose dragons can quickly direct their fire at targets below, above, and to the sides of their flight path have distinct advantage over those who must steer to fly directly at their targets and fire.
Assuming a bridle bit in her mouth for steerage (it could some other way) how do I set up the classic video game scheme of moving vs. pointing and shooting - on a dragon’s back? Thank you!

After some feedback, thank you:

The reason the king must put riders on dragons is because his enemy does it. Guided by their pilots, the dragons strike at human infrastructure with precision: battlements; dwellings; water supplies; food stores; caches of arms; factories. The king does not understand his enemy is the problem, and unless he figures it out, he and his people are doomed.

Comment: if they can understand human speech wouldn't a simple word order suffice to make them spit fire.

Comment: A bridle bit seems to be the worst possible solution if the dragon is breathing fire, not to mention unwanted by the free ones.  If dragons are intelligent then the solution seems both trivial and unnecessary - let the dragon pick its own targets and get rid of the unnecessary human weighing it down!

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 a rider is still probably essential so the dragon can pick targets. I mean yeah a dog can understand certain words but still is not intelligent enough to understand the situation it's in. So i don't think a dragon knows battle tactics automatically. And even if it does how does it know how to contribute effectively in battle with out communication?

Comment: @Fallenspacerock: *"With out communication":* What's wrong with [bugle calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugle_call) and military music in general? Those were used for millennia to signal attack, retreat, charge, wheel left, wheel right, form line and so on.

Comment: How accurate do you need to be? I mean, are you aiming your dragonfire at a big block of hundreds of troops, or are you trying to pick out specific individuals, or something in between?

Comment: @AlexP just saying that it is easier to coordinate dragons when they have a rider with them.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock the dragons are stated to be intelligent, even if human language skills vary.  With the minimal info provided, there is no reason to believe that a human rider will be better at maintaining situational awareness on a dragon flying evasively through the air than the dragon itself will be, nor is there any reason to believe that the humans will have superior tactical skills.  As for deflection estimation, a human will undoubtedly be worse at "leading the target" than a dragon that has been doing it since it started flying.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 we don't know how intelligent the dragons are and i am very certain if they are intelligent enough to to know tactics they would not let them selves be treated like horses. What you are suggesting is that horses would be better with out human intervention in warfare or take drones for a more modern example. The point i am getting at is that i don't think that they can act i such a way independently that it would be tactical advantages without a rider.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock the purpose of comments is to prompt *the OP* to improve the question by adding information, not to get *your* speculation.  (And if you ride intelligent horses with a breath weapon, feel free to post an answer re how you aim them.)

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 this was exactly my intention. I am just of the opinion that riders are necessary under the circumstances I see in the question. So i saw no reason why this question should be changed in such a way.

Comment: First of all, thank you all so much! I’ll be back for sure! This is very cool.

Comment: The reason the king must put riders on dragons is because his enemy does it. Guided by their pilots, the dragons strike at human infrastructure with precision: battlements; dwellings; water supplies; food stores; caches of arms; factories. The king does not understand his enemy is the problem, and unless he figures it out, he and his people are doomed.

Comment: @Clarkman so he basically copies his enemy and doesn't know why he copies them. I mean what benefits is he awere of that putting a rider on a dragon archives?